# Image not showing into html header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to load an image from a url however whenever page is loaded it is always null any help will be appreciated

i also tried using src attribute and also did it from css as well but still it's not working

Here is what my header looks like:

[Header Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YvTp.png)

here is my code:

```css
html, body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-color: #181A1B;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    .logo{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        content:url("https://pasteboard.co/K18aDZ4.jpg");
    }
    .header{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        position:relative;
        background-color: #242627;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    .profilepic{
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        content:url("https://pasteboard.co/K18aDZ4.jpg");
    }
    .profile{
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        float: right;
    }
    
    #name{
        font-size: 15px;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">
    </head>
    <header class="header">
        <img class="logo" />
        <div class="profile">
            <img class="profilepic" />
        <label id="name">ABCD</label>
        </div>
    </header>
    <body>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you show console errors if you have?

Comment: @tmsbrndz there are no console errors however i'm just getting white borders around image i'll post it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with your code

The problem is the image link

You can put another image link and see that your code is completely correct

**Example:**

```css
html, body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-color: #181A1B;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    .logo{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        content:url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/example-red-tag-example-red-square-price-tag-117502755.jpg");
    }
    .header{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        position:relative;
        background-color: #242627;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    .profilepic{
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        content:url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/example-red-tag-example-red-square-price-tag-117502755.jpg");
    }
    .profile{
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        float: right;
    }
    
    #name{
        font-size: 15px;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">
    </head>
    <header class="header">
        <img class="logo" />
        <div class="profile">
            <img class="profilepic" />
        <label id="name">ABCD</label>
        </div>
    </header>
    <body>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Unable to recognize image

If you are careful, when you open the link, the image will be displayed a few seconds later

Also, the contents of the link are not just images

**Use the link that contains the contents of the image to insert the image**

**pay attention:
Whatever the link is, there is no reason why its contents should be based on the same link**

**for example:**

**I think because the end of the link is `.jpg`
You think the contents of this link are definitely an image and should be displayed**

**but in reality it is not.**

**The link can be anything**

I suggest you read more about [`urls`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) , [`headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and [`htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use background instead of content. The css property is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect the problem is of **pasteboard**.
You can use photobucket.com instead, which will do the same but in more efficient manner!